# In-memory XML manipulation

Tags: xml, openxml, linq-to-xml, memorystream, file-manipulation

I'm trying to do a find and replace in an `OpenXML` word document which I've openened into a `MemoryStream`.

```
using (WordprocessingDocument _document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(_ms, true))
{
    var placeHolder = _document.MainDocumentPart.Document
                          .Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text>()
                          .Where(node => node.InnerText.Contains("***PlaceHolderText***"))
                          .FirstOrDefault();

    placeHolder.InnerText.Replace("***PlaceHolderText***", "hello world!");
}
```

This doesn't work. I'm not sure why, but manipulating the document in this way doesn't seem
to have any affect on the `MemoryStream`.

I found [this blog by Eric White](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericwhite/working-with-in-memory-open-xml-documents) which does something similar, but I still can't quite get it. He uses an `XDocument`, so I've got something like the following:

```
XDocument doc = _document.MainDocumentPart.GetXDocument(); // this is an extension method
var textNodes = doc.DescendantNodes().Where(n => n.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text);
```

This finds the right nodes in my document, but the problem is now I can't work out how to change the text. The `System.Xml.Linq.XNodes` which I end up with this way (instead of the `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text` nodes I really want) don't have an `InnerText` or `Value` property or anything like that. I can't see any way to get the text from the nodes, or update them. I tried casting the node but that didn't compile.

Am I even going in the right direction? Or is there an easier way? Any pointers would be very much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got this working. Taking the first code snippet, the last line should read `placeHolder.Text` and not `placeHolder.InnerText`. Can't believe I wasted 4 hours on that! :(

Answer (score 1):

To the first part (updating the `MemoryStream`).
You should think about the memory stream as read only as it is passed to the `Open` method. The parser has read through the stream and built another in memory representation that is not connected tot he input stream. You'll have to write it back out using `Save`.

As for manipulating an XNode's textual content you are looking for [XText.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xtext.value.aspx).

Comment: "You'll have to write it back out using Save" - which Save method are you talking about?